# How to stop anonymous access to redis databases

Tags: redis, docker-compose

I run redis image with docker-compose
I passed **redis.conf** (and redis says "configuration loaded")
In **redis.conf** i added user

```
user pytest ><password> ~pytest/* on @set @get
```

And yet I can communicate with redis as anonymous
even with uncommented string

```
requirepass <password>
```

Redis docs about topics: [Security](https://redis.io/topics/security) and [ACL](https://redis.io/topics/acl) do not answer how to restrict access to everyone. Probably I do not understand something fundamentally.

my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 6000s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - redis-db:/data
      - redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]


volumes:
  redis-db:
  redis.conf:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And yet I can communicate with redis as anonymous even with uncommented string

Because there's a **default** user, and you didn't disable it. If you want to totally disable anonymous access, you should add the following to your redis.conf:

```
user default off
```

Secondly, the configuration for user 'pytest' is incorrect. If you want to only allow user 'pytest' to have `set` and `get` command on the given key pattern, you should configure it as follows:

```
user pytest ><password> ~pytest/* on +set +get
```

Comment: So obvious and logical yet so implicit. Thank you. I'll try it later but seems that it should work

Answer (score 1):

You also need to **ensure that the docker-compose is using your config file**.
Assuming you have the `redis.conf` in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` the 'volumes' section in the service declaration would be.

```
  - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

and also **remove** the named volume declaration in the bottom

```
redis.conf:
```

The users would be able to connect to Redis but without [AUTH](https://redis.io/commands/auth) they can't perform any action if you enable

```
requirepass <password>
```

The right way to restrict [GET](https://redis.io/commands/get), [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set) operations on the keys pytest/* would be

```
user pytest ><password> ~pytest/* on +set +get
```

Comment: if i user redis-conf on volumes section i have to declare volume. Otherwise docker raises error that volume has no declaration